# Why aren't my questions populating in the ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm trying to populate a ListBox in a child window based off what a user has selected in the previous window using Radio Buttons. This is my method.

```
private void ListBoxQuestions() 
{
    MainWindow a = new MainWindow();

    if (a.Beginner.IsChecked == true) {
        ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 2 + 2?");
        ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 32 + 5?");
        ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 42 + 7?");
        ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 8 + 15?");
        ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 4 + 2?");
    }
}
```

All I'm trying to say is if the user has selected that RadioButton then add these questions to the ListBox in the next window. But it doesn't work and nothing is populated in the ListBox. Would there be a better way to reference parent properties to child windows? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 'new MainWindow()' creates a new window, It does not give you reference to any existing window. Is it really what you want?

Comment: @Ondra is there a way to properly add a reference to an existing window?

Comment: If Beginner is RadioButton name and ListBoxQuestions() method is in same class. then use this in place of 'a'. it should do the trick.

Comment: @KyloRen unfortunately they are not in the same class. Is there a better way to reference that radio button from the mainWindow to a childWindow?

Comment: @markoGrbovic well you can set Window.owner property while opening new window. and then retrieve the parent window as this.owner from child window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a public static variable as follows:

Add the following code to your Main Form:

```
public static bool BegginerChecked;
```

Then double click on your RadioButton and add the following code inside the void it creates:

```
BegginerChecked = Begginer.IsChecked;
```

Your final code in your main form will look like this:

```
public static bool BegginerChecked;
private void Begginer_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BegginerChecked = Begginer.IsChecked;
}
```

Then change the code in your child form to the following:

```
private void ListBoxQuestions()
{
    if (MainWindow.BegginerChecked == true)
    {
        ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 2 + 2?");
        ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 32 + 5?");
        ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 42 + 7?");
        ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 8 + 15?");
        ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 4 + 2?");
    }
}
```

Comment: When I add that BegginerChecked = Begginer.Checked; line it gives me an error saying 'Toggle.Checked' can only appear on the left side of += or -=

Comment: @markoGrbovic I updated the answer, does it work now?

Comment: I made the change to IsChecked instead of Checked and it still raises an error. It says 'Cannot implicitly convert type bool? to bool. An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?) '

Comment: I just casted it to a bool and it woked!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, there are two windows, e.g. `MainWindow` and `SecondWindow`.
Let's suppose you want to populate `ListBox` of `SecondWindow` from `MainWindow`, then your code should look like that:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       SecondWindow secondWindow = new SecondWindow();
       secondWindow.listBox.Items.Add("What is 2 + 2?");
       secondWindow.listBox.Items.Add("What is 32 + 5?");
       secondWindow.listBox.Items.Add("What is 42 + 7?");
       secondWindow.listBox.Items.Add("What is 8 + 15?");
       secondWindow.listBox.Items.Add("What is 4 + 2?");
       secondWindow.Show();//or ShowDialog() if you want to show a modal window
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You can use `Application` object. You can store stuff in the `Properties` collection. For example, you should set value in the `Properties` to `BeginnerChecked` in the MainWindow:

```
Application.Current.Properties["fooBar"] = "BegginerChecked";
```

Then in the `SecondWindow` you should read `Application.Current.Properties["fooBar"]` and fill your `ListBox`:

```
if((string)Application.Current.Properties["fooBar"]=="BegginerChecked")
   ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 2 + 2?");
   ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 32 + 5?");
   ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 42 + 7?");
   ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 8 + 15?");
   ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 4 + 2?");
```

Comment: Your understanding is correct but I am looking for a way to pass a value from one window to another. The Radio button is on the first window and when I select one of the 3 radio buttons and click ok, the secondary window should show the listbox populated with the questions.

Answer (score 0):

Open your new `window` in `MainWindow` like this:

```
Window newWindow = new Window();
newWindow.Owner = this;
newWindow.Show();
```

In the new `window` do:

```
private void ListBoxQuestions()
{
    MainWindow a = this.owner as MainWindow;//mainWindow is type of the window current window is opened
    if (a.Beginner.IsChecked == true) 
    {
        ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 2 + 2?");
        ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 32 + 5?");
        ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 42 + 7?");
        ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 8 + 15?");
        ListBoxQ.Items.Add("What is 4 + 2?");
    }
}
```